Unable to find command: plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
Unable to find command: plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
"@ionic/angular": "^8.0.0",
"@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^11.0.1",

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Solution:
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser --save --debug

